# Renomear grande massa de arquivos

Tags: java

Estou tentando criar um script em java para renomear uma grande quantidade de arquivos aplicando um padrão na formatação que seria:

- Primeira letra maiúscula e o restante minúscula.
- Nomes compostos com mais de uma palavra devem seguir o padrão acima para cada nome.
- A extenção dos arquivos deve ficar minúscula.

Dado isso, tenho 3 arquivos modelos:
douglas leonardo.smc
XGR - STS.SMC
xpto.smc

Quero o seguinte resultado:
Douglas Leonardo.smc
Xgr - Sts.smc
Xpto.smc

No arquivo **douglas leonardo.smc**, eu consegui deixar o **d** de douglas maiúsculo, mas o **l** de leonardo não. O arquivo está assm:
Douglas leonardo.smc.

Resumindo: Quando a String é composta por mais de uma palavra, somente a primeira eu consigo deixar inciando com letra maiúscula, o restante não. Como posso resolver?

```
import java.io.File;

public class RenomeiaArquivos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File diretorio = new File("/home/douglas/Documentos/roms");
        File[] files = diretorio.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            String nomeArquivo = files[i].getName();
            nomeArquivo = nomeArquivo.toLowerCase();
            String primeiraMaiuscula;
            primeiraMaiuscula = nomeArquivo.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
            String restanteMiniscula;
            restanteMiniscula = nomeArquivo.substring(1);

            nomeArquivo = primeiraMaiuscula + restanteMiniscula;

            System.out.println(nomeArquivo);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828111/making-first-letter-capital-using-regex-like-in-ucwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro você pode fazer um split(dividir) pelos espaços, depois ir em cada parte alterando a primeira letra, e por fim mandar a extensão para *lowercase*, aqui esta um codigo completo :

```
String ext = "";
if(nome.lastIndexOf(".")>0){
    ext = nome.substring(nome.lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase();
    nome= nome.substring(0,nome.lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase();
}
String nomeFinal = "";
String partes[] = nome.split("\\s+");
for(int i =0; i<partes.length; i++){
    nomeFinal += " " +  
        (partes[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + 
        partes[i].length()>1 ? partes[i].substring(1) : "");
}
nomeFinal = nomeFinal.substring(1) + ext;//Pra remover um espaço que fica no inicio devido ao 1 for
```

Answer (score 1):

Usar expressões regulares dariam um pouco mais de flexibilidade. Veja um exemplo:

```
public class WordUpperCaseExample {

    public static final Locale pt_BR = new Locale("pt","BR");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] examples = { "douglas léonardo.smc", "XGR - STS.SMC", "xpto.smc", "aRqUiVo_cOmPoStO.tXt", "aRqUiVo-cOmPoStO.tXt", "123nome.txt" };
        for (String e : examples) {
            System.out.println(upperCaseWords(e));
        }
    }

    public static String upperCaseWords(String phrase) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\.?[\\p{IsAlphabetic}][\\w\\d&&[^_]]*", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher(phrase);
        StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) m.appendReplacement(sb, upperCaseFirst(m.group()));
        return m.appendTail(sb).toString();
    }

    public static String upperCaseFirst(String word) {
        return word.isEmpty() ? word :
                word.length() == 1 ? word.toUpperCase(pt_BR) :
                        word.startsWith(".") ? word.toLowerCase(pt_BR) : (word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(pt_BR) + word.substring(1).toLowerCase(pt_BR));
    }

}
```

A expressão regular `\\.?[\\p{IsAlphabetic}][\\w\\d&&[^_]]*` pode parecer complexa, mas ela procura por palavras que:

1. `\\.?`: opcionalmente comecem com um ponto, o que seria a extensão do arquivo. Portanto eu verifico se o grupo capturado começa com ponto e, caso seja verdadeiro, ele converte tudo para minúscula.
2. `[\\p{IsAlphabetic}]`: força com que o primeiro caracter do grupo capturado pela expressão seja um caractere alfabético na tabela Unicode. Isso faz com que, por exemplo, `123nome` vire `123Nome`, já que a expressão vai capturar apenas começando da primeira letra. Essa restrição também faz com que outros caracteres dividindo palavras não sejam capturados.
3. `[\\w\\d&&[^_]]*` faz com que as demais letras e números sejam capturados enquanto `&&[^_]` desconsidera o "sublinhado* (*underscore*). Isso faz com que `abc_abc` vire `Abc_Abc`.

Além disso, o parâmetro `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` faz com que caracteres da tabela Unicode sejam considerados, então, por exemplo, `\w` vai capturar caracteres acentuados como `á` além dos que pertencem ao padrão ASCII como `a`.

O método `upperCaseFirst` faz a conversão de cada palavra. Ele contém qualquer lógica adicional necessário para converter uma palavra capturada. As regras do exemplo acima são:

1. Palavra vazia, não faz nada. Isto é só por precaução, já que a expressão regular não permite que isso ocorra. Assim o método pode ser reusado com segurança e eficiência.
2. Palavra com um caractere, converte para maiúscula. Entretanto você pode querer mudar isso, de modo que `olhe a casa` vire `Olhe a Casa` e não `Olhe A Casa` como está agora.
3. Se a palavra começa com um ponto, converte para minúscula. Isso é para tratar o caso da extensão do arquivo, mas pode causar efeitos colaterais, caso haja outros pontos no nome do arquivo. Se você quiser tratar isso, é melhor tratar a extensão em separado como na resposta no Rodrigo.
4. Nos demais casos, converte o primeiro caractere para maiúscula e o restante para minúsculas. Observe que eu sempre especifico o *locale* para realizar as operações de conversão. Isso evita possíveis inconsistências caso o programa seja executado em diferentes ambientes onde a língua do Java esteja diferente.

A ideia geral da implementação é que você pode facilmente adicionar e modificar as regras alterando a expressão regular conforme a [documentação da classe `Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) permite e também o método `upperCaseFirst`.